# Practice for complex electronic circuits

Tags: practical

I'm self-learning electronics; I've watched Anant Agarwal videos and read his book and another book "Electronic Devices And Circuit Theory- Robert L. Boylestad".

But, now, I need to practice more on building complex circuits like those involving multiple transistors or more than, say, 10 components.[please don't tell me that's not complex because it's still complex for me.]

so, where do I begin? are there online video courses or books for that purpose? What's your recommendation

and one more question, where do I begin for PIC microcontrollers?

Comment: Find an itch. Scratch it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting out PIC Programming](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/442/starting-out-pic-programming)

Answer (score 2):

You begin by starting the process, *period*.  This is not a linear process.  The important thing is to start *somewhere*.

If you're interested in online video courses, Google for them.  If you're interested in dead tree books, Google for them (as always, "[The Art of Electronics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521370957)" is a must have.)

If, for example, you're interested in audio amplifier circuits, Amazon will give you a number of selections at various levels of sophistication.  You'll also find a wide variety of DIY forums (of varying quality).

This site is for specific conceptual questions so this is not so much an answer as an encouragement:  get started reading and building.

When you encounter something specific you don't understand and can't seem to get past, come back with a specific question.  And, don't worry if it doesn't make sense immediately.  Often, after a period of time, what didn't make sense at all seems crystal clear.

That's what I mean by this being a non-linear process.  You'll read things that don't quite make sense but, *when you review these later, after more reading and practice and letting your mind "connect the dots", they make perfect sense.*